# Two queries, merge results, sort

Tags: php, mysql

I am new at this and stuck for days...trying everything I could find from Google and these Forums.

I have one MySQL table that I need to pull data from.

I need to pull all records where `AgentID = 1234`
Also, pull all records where `OfficeID  =  4321` (and `AgentID != 1234` to prevent dupes)
Then display the results with AgentID records first, if they exist, then the OfficeID records.

I tried a UNION, but could not find a way to sort or show Agent first, Office second.
Tried array_merge and two queries/results, but the merged data was mixed instead of Agent First data, again, with no way to sort by Agent first.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in the ORDER BY to impose your specified conditions.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE AgentID = 1234
        OR (OfficeID = 4321 AND AgentID <> 1234)
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN AgentId = 1234 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
             AgentID, OfficeID
```

Comment: Thanks all...I solved with this that someone suggested:

SELECT *, IF(AgentID = 1234, 1, 2) AS AgentsFirst FROM AgentsTable WHERE AgentID = 1234 OR OfficeID  =  4321 ORDER BY AgentsFirst

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
( SELECT 1 AS batch_no, .... FROM .... ) # the query with AgentID - the one that you want displayed first
 UNION
( SELECT 2 AS batch_no, .... FROM .... ) 

ORDER BY batch_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE AgentId = 1234 OR (OfficeId = 4321 AND AgentId != 1234)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AgentId = 1234 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```